# SQL GROUP CONCAT and LEFT JOIN return only one result from database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, group-concat

Am trying to run sql query that can return all user post and also join post image if the user attached image while submiting a post. But using the below code it only return data from `post table` when the `post id` exsit on `post image id` table if not it will ignore all post without images. How can i write a query that return both post with image and without?

Below are my table structure

Table vendor_account

```
eu_vendor_id | uname |  mypagename
-------------|-------|--------------
v801         | peter |  pageA
v900         | john  |
```

Table social_posts

```
social_page_id  |  post_id | vendor_owner_id | post_body_message
----------------|----------|-----------------|------------------------------
pageA           |  p100    |  v801            | This is post without image
pageA           |  p101    |  v801            | This is post with 2 images
pageA           |  p102    |  v801            | This is post with 1 image
```

Table social_post_photos

```
img | post_image_id | photo_url
----|---------------|---------------
1   | p101          | image1.png
2   | p101          | image2.png
3   | p102          | image01.png
```

My SQL Query

```
SELECT 
im.post_image_id, p.post_body_message,
group_concat(im.photo_url ORDER BY im.photo_url) imgs
FROM social_post_photos im

LEFT JOIN social_posts p
ON p.post_id = im.post_image_id

INNER JOIN vendor_account v
ON p.vendor_owner_id = v.eu_vendor_id

WHERE p.social_page_id = 'pageA'
AND p.vendor_owner_id = 'v801'

GROUP BY im.post_image_id
```

Current result
When i run the above sql query it will return it will result like below and ignore other post that doen't have image attached to it

```
post_image_id  |  post_body_message         |  photo_url
---------------|----------------------------|-------------------------
p101           | This is post with 2 images | [IMAGE1.PNG],[IMAGE2.PNG]
p102           | This is post with 1 image  | [IMAGE01.PNG]
```

My expected result
I want have a query that can return all data even when it has no image since i used `LEFT JOIN` because is not mandatly that the post will have a photo attached to it

```
post_image_id  |  post_body_message         |  photo_url
---------------|----------------------------|-------------------------
p101           | This is post with 2 images | [IMAGE1.PNG],[IMAGE2.PNG]
p102           | This is post with 1 image  | [IMAGE01.PNG]
p100           | This is post without image | null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are selecting from the `social_post_photos` you would need to change your join to `social_posts` to a `RIGHT JOIN` in order to get all records from `social_posts`. Since I abhor `RIGHT JOIN`s, and have yet to find a good reason to ever use one, I would instead suggest you change the order of the tables to select from `social_posts` AND `LEFT JOIN` to `social_post_photos`:

```
SELECT 
p.post_id, p.post_body_message,
group_concat(im.photo_url ORDER BY im.photo_url) imgs
FROM social_posts p

LEFT JOIN social_post_photos im
ON im.post_image_id = p.post_id
INNER JOIN vendor_account v
ON p.vendor_owner_id = v.eu_vendor_id

WHERE p.social_page_id = 'pageA'
AND p.vendor_owner_id = 'v801'

GROUP BY p.post_id, p.post_body_message
```

N.B. In doing this you also need to select (and group by) `p.post_id` instead of `im.post_image_id`.

Answer (score 0):

When `LEFT JOIN`, move the right side table conditions from the `WHERE` clauseto the `ON` clause (otherwise you'll get regular `INNER JOIN` result):

```
SELECT 
im.post_image_id, p.post_body_message,
group_concat(im.photo_url ORDER BY im.photo_url) imgs
FROM social_post_photos im

LEFT JOIN social_posts p
ON p.post_id = im.post_image_id
AND p.social_page_id = 'pageA'
AND p.vendor_owner_id = 'v801'

INNER JOIN vendor_account v
ON p.vendor_owner_id = v.eu_vendor_id


GROUP BY im.post_image_id
```

Nothe that you have an invalid `group by`. It won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Still return only two data

Answer (score 0):

From your post:

```
INNER JOIN vendor_account v
ON p.vendor_owner_id = v.eu_vendor_id
```

This part will cut your results to 2 max, since you only have 1 vendor ID (peter) that's your only result (I assume that's the single line you're getting).

In order to get both lines you'll need to `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` the last table. Also the Where condition will only select one post and one vendor, I'm not sure that's what you want.

```
SELECT 
im.post_image_id, p.post_body_message,
group_concat(im.photo_url ORDER BY im.photo_url) imgs
FROM social_post_photos im

LEFT JOIN social_posts p
ON p.post_id = im.post_image_id

LEFT JOIN vendor_account v
ON p.vendor_owner_id = v.eu_vendor_id

-- -- I DON'T KNOW IF THIS IS RIGHT?!
-- WHERE p.social_page_id = 'pageA'
-- AND p.vendor_owner_id = 'v801'

GROUP BY im.post_image_id
```

Here's a fiddle with everything you need: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7ce30/17

Answer (score 0):

U can try below code.

```html
SELECT 
im.post_image_id, p.post_body_message,
group_concat(im.photo_url ORDER BY im.photo_url) imgs
FROM social_posts p

LEFT JOIN social_post_photos im
ON p.post_id = im.post_image_id

INNER JOIN vendor_account v
ON p.vendor_owner_id = v.eu_vendor_id

WHERE p.social_page_id = 'pageA'
AND p.vendor_owner_id = 'v801'

GROUP BY im.post_image_id
```